# SSIS package save error - an invalid character was found in text content (msxml6.dll)

Tags: ssis

I am tearing my hair out with this one. I have a large SSIS package (2.5Mb) that includes 3 ConnectionManagers each of which have an expression attached for dynamic assignment of the ConnectionString dependent upon the value of a user variable - CountryCode. I got this to work for one value of CountryCode (="AUS") but, when I change the value to "USA" and try to save it immediately afterwards, I get the error above ("an invalid character was found in text content (msxml6.dll)") but with no line number or useful further info that might help me tie down the problem. I am guessing that the failure has nothing to do with the "USA" text that I simply typed over the "AUS" text but is linked to the assignment of the ConnectionString associated with "USA". Would that be a fair assumption? I have examined the ConnectionSTring with a fine tooth comb but can't see a problem with it. Any suggestions would be welcomed, thanks.

Comment: what type of connecting you are using?\

Comment: I'm curious what each of the expressions look like on each of the connection strings.  Could you share that?  Or where country code is getting evaluated to determine what the connection string should be. Maybe in a variable.

Comment: The one that's failing contains a password - is it OK to explicitly include a password in an expression that's used to assign the ConnectionString property. Will post detail shortly.

Comment: The epression looks like this  @[User::VarCountryCode] == "AUS" ? "Data Source=blah-de-blah     ;Provider=SQLNCLI11  ;Integrated Security=SSPI;" :
@[User::VarCountryCode] == "UK"  ? "Data Source=dum-de-dum                     ;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=AnotherId;password=password" :
@[User::VarCountryCode] == "USA" ? "Data Source=fiddle-de-dee;Provider=SQLNCLI11  ;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=MyId;password=password" :
""

Comment: Oh and the actual passwords do include non alphabetic characters. Not sure if that could be triggering it?

Comment: I think this issue is down to the fact that the name of the USA server in the Connection String has a single backslash in it. If I change it to a double backslash I can at least save the package although it leaves me with a different problem which I need to investigate. I think it's extremely lame that the error message gives no clue whatsoever as to where the problem is located. Thanks very much for replies.

Comment: @JustNod your expression looked fine, I was wonder if it was something like that, a special character or maybe the string included a non-printable character that was throwing the error.  Seems odd that it was throwing that particular error because of a single backslash.   The expressions builder would usually give you an indication of illegal escape sequence of "...." and tell you.  But glad you found it.